# XSLT Dynamic Tag Insertion for bullet point elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I've only just started to get my head around XSLT and looking through the W3school examples to address a new task my employer has given me.

I have a few files I need to convert with XML structures as follows.

```
     <tablecell bgcolor='white'>
<pardef id='16' leftmargin='0.2757in' list='bullet' keepwithnext='true' keeptogether='true'/>
        <par def='34'>
            <run>
                <font size='8pt' name='Verdana' pitch='variable' truetype='true'
     familyid='20' color='navy'/>Data in bullet point 1</run>
        </par>
        <par def='34'>
            <run>
                <font size='8pt' name='Verdana' pitch='variable' truetype='true'
     familyid='20' color='navy'/>Data in bullet point 2</run>
        </par>
        <par def='34'>
            <run>
                <font size='8pt' name='Verdana' pitch='variable' truetype='true'
     familyid='20' color='navy'/>Data in bullet point 3</run>
        </par>
        <par def='34'>
            <run>
                <font size='8pt' name='Verdana' pitch='variable' truetype='true'
     familyid='20' color='navy'/>Data in bullet point 4</run>
        </par>
    </tablecell>
```

What I have so far for my XSL to process the xml is as follows.

```
    <xsl:template match="tablecell">
            <td>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@colspan" />
                <!--<xsl:value-of select="."/> -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="par" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="pardef" />
            </td>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pardef">
        <xsl:if test="@list='bullet'">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par">
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="run" />
            </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="run">
            <li>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="run" />
            </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

The problem I am having is I'm not sure as to the best way to dynamically insert the closing `</ul>` tag after the last `<run>` element to create the bullet points. In practice there could be any number of `<run>` tags in my XML files to be transformed.

Is this where I need to do something with a variable and count the number of  elements and then do some processing based on this variable?

The other situation that I need guidance on catering for is that the `<run>` tags should only be surrounded by `<li>` tags if they are under the structure pardef/par where the pardef element has the attribute list='bullet'.

This is the output I am trying to achieve.

```
<p>
    <ul>
        <li>Data in bullet point 1</li>
        <li>Data in bullet point 2</li>
        <li>Data in bullet point 3</li>
        <li>Data in bullet point 4</li>
    </ul>  
</p>
```

If you could point me in the right direction for the two queries mentioned above that would be appreciated.

Cheers

---

Not sure how to continue this existing thread with more code snippets apart from Editing the existing thread. If you can let me know how to do that it would be great.

Thanks all that have helped with this problem so far. Someone responded to this post previously with the idea to use modes which has helped me get further. 
The question I have now is the following situation where if there are `<par>` tags encountered with attribute def=16 I want it to use the mode='sixteen' template otherwise use the generic basic par template which very simply just uses `<p>` `</p>` tags. 
How does one achieve this? Right now I am thinking of using an if statement but  would that be the best practice way to do it?

Also, does the below code mean that `<par>` elements are potentially processed twice?

```
<xsl:template match="tablecell">
        <td>
            <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="@colspan" /> -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="par" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />

            <!-- Apply to par elements where attribute def=16 -->   
            <xsl:apply-templates select="par[@def='16']" mode='sixteen' />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template for par elements where attribute def=16 -->
    <xsl:template match="par" mode='sixteen'>
        <ul>
            <!-- Apply to any table elements -->    
            <xsl:apply-templates select="run" mode='bullet' />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
```

This is my attempt, not sure if it's correct or best practice.

```
  <xsl:template match="tablecell">
        <td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="par[@def='16']">
                    <!-- Apply to par elements where attribute def=16 -->   
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="par[@def='16']" mode='sixteen' />

                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="par" />

                </xsl:otherwise>


            </xsl:choose>
<xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Personally, I find w3schools is often a handy site for looking up things you have forgotten because you don't use them often, but it's not a great tutorial site for people learning a language for the first time. Note also that it has nothing to do with W3C.

Answer (score 0):

The key point you are missing is that XSLT doesn't create start and end tags in the output, it creates a tree of nodes. You can't write half a node to a tree. A "literal result element" like `<ul> XXX </ul>` is a single instruction that (a) evaluates XXX to create some content, and (b) creates a UL element node to which that content is attached. You must think of `<ul></ul>` as one instruction that constructs a node, not as an instruction that creates a start tag followed by an instruction that creates an end tag.

Your problem is a classic positional grouping problem. In fact it's one of the examples used in the XSLT specification for the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction: search for "Example: Grouping Alternating Sequences of Elements" in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-for-each-group . Note that this instruction requires XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0. In many environments the default XSLT processor still only supports XSLT 1.0. It's much harder to solve this problem in 1.0 (it's not impossible, but it's a significant challenge for a newcomer to the language). So make sure you're using a processor that supports 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: I had a read through the article you posted but found it quite confusing in terms of the usage. Another post made to this question suggested the use of modes which has worked for me BUT it brings up a related query.

Comment: Modes on their own aren't going to solve a grouping problem for you, though they might be part of the solution. I'm afraid I can't suggest anything other than keep reading until you understand the concepts. There are several good books on XSLT 2.0. Jeni Tennison's is a good beginner's tutorial, my book aims to go deeper into the underlying concepts and provide a more comprehensive reference for all the instructions.